# Share posts on Facebook automatically from Laravel back-end

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5

let me tell you what I have done.

Step 1:

```
"require": {
    "sammyk/laravel-facebook-sdk": "^3.0"
}
```

Step 2:

```
'providers' => [
       SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\LaravelFacebookSdkServiceProvider::class,
 ];

 'aliases' => [
      'Facebook' => SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\FacebookFacade::class,
 ];
```

Step 3:

```
D:\Working_Dir\htdocs\social_test>php artisan vendor:publish
```

> Copied File
>   [\vendor\sammyk\laravel-facebook-sdk\src\config\laravel-facebook-sdk
>   .php] To [\config\laravel-facebook-sdk.php] Publishing complete for
>   tag []!

Step 4:

in config/laravel-facebook-sdk.php gave app_id, app_secret, default_graph_version.

Step5 :

in Controller `use Facebook;` at top. I want to share posts automatically from back-end to users wall. this is my code.

```
public function doShare(Request $request) {

    $fb = new Facebook();
    $data = [
        'message' => 'This is a sample sharing',
        'source' => $fb->fileToUpload(asset('photo.jpg')),
    ];

    try {

      $response = $fb->post('/me/photos', $data, '{access-token}');
      var_dump($response);
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }
        $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
        echo 'Photo ID: ' . $graphNode['id'];
}
```

And got this code from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_upload_photo). But it always gives this error

> FatalErrorException in FacebookController.php line 21:
>   Call to undefined method SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\FacebookFacade::fileToUpload()

Anyone give me a help or hint to do this. And if I want to know how to get *{access-token}* also.

Comment: any luck so far ?

Comment: It's because the `facebook/graph-sdk` and `sammyk/laravel-facebook-sdk` are two different composer packages. They both have their own classes, methods, and different documentations.

Comment: Have you created an App on developers.facebook.com already? Because you will need it to execute OAuth2 with your App and Facebook, so that you can "do" something with users' data and actions.